# Two nodes publish to one topic

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two node publishing message to cmd_vel topic. One node is for self-driving, the other one is for teleoperation. How to set the teleoperation node has the high priority when publishing to cmd_vel?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208629/two-nodes-publish-to-one-topic/) by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2015-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/cmd_vel_mux solves this.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2